# Want FTP server (VSFTPD) configured for file sharing on fedora

Tags: linux, fedora, ftp, vsftpd

I am using fedora to host a FTP server for internal use and I am using vsftpd for this.
It is using the configuration file `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf`.

The configuration I am using is as follows:

```
    listen=YES
    anonymous_enable=YES
    local_enable=YES
    write_enable=YES
    anon_upload_enable=YES
    anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
    dirmessage_enable=YES
    xferlog_enable=YES
    connect_from_port_20=YES
    chown_uploads=YES
    chown_username=username
    ftpd_banner=Welcome to blah FTP service.
    pam_service_name=vsftpd
    rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/vsftpd.pem
    anon_root=/home/ftp
    anon_umask=022
    local_umask=022
    file_open_mode=0777
```

Whatever I do, the file uploaded by anonymous user is `-rw-------`
and the directory created is `drwxrwxrwx`.

I want the uploaded file to be `-rw-rw-rw-`. 
What am I doing wrong here? Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know enough to give an answer, but I think you may be confusing umask and chmod permissions. See `man umask` for more information.

Comment: I understand thats why I am using 022 which should give 755 for directions and 644 for files. correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to change the "local_umask" value in the config file to "000". Although I've not used FTP daemons in a good while, this is what was usually the problem when I was getting permission modes I didn't want.

Comment: I will try this.